# how to use listctrl in notebook wxPython

Tags: wxpython

I have one question.. wxPython listctrl in notebook

I created 2 tab use notebook.

I added button in first tab and added Listctrl in second tab.

If i click the button, Add value in Listctrl to second tab.
how to solve this problem?

```
import wx

class PageOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.query_find_btn = wx.Button(self, 4, "BTN", (40,40))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.AddList, id = 4)

    def AddList(self, evt):
        self.list1.InsertStringItem(0,'Hello')

class PageTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.list1 = wx.ListCtrl(self,-1,wx.Point(0,0),wx.Size(400,400),style=wx.LC_REPORT |   wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
    self.list1.InsertColumn(0,'values')

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title,size=(400,400),pos=wx.Point(100,100), 
        style=wx.SYSTEM_MENU |wx.CAPTION )

        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

        MainFrame = PageOne(nb)
        SecondFrame = PageTwo(nb)

        nb.AddPage(MainFrame, "One")
        nb.AddPage(SecondFrame, "Two")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame=MyFrame(None,-1,'Unknown.py')
        self.frame.Centre()
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [using listctrl in notebook wxPython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769937/using-listctrl-in-notebook-wxpython)

Comment: Don't create new thread with the same question !! I send this question to admin as duplicate !!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to approach this. You can do it the silly way, like this:

```
import wx

class PageOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.query_find_btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "BTN", (40,40))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.AddList, self.query_find_btn)

    def AddList(self, evt):
        frame = self.GetTopLevelParent()
        frame.pageTwo.list1.InsertStringItem(0,'Hello')

class PageTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.list1 = wx.ListCtrl(self,-1,wx.Point(0,0),wx.Size(400,400),style=wx.LC_REPORT |   wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.list1.InsertColumn(0,'values')

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title,size=(400,400),pos=wx.Point(100,100), 
        style=wx.SYSTEM_MENU |wx.CAPTION )

        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

        self.pageOne = PageOne(nb)
        self.pageTwo = PageTwo(nb)

        nb.AddPage(self.pageOne, "One")
        nb.AddPage(self.pageTwo, "Two")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame=MyFrame(None,-1,'Unknown.py')
        self.frame.Centre()
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Or you can use pubsub, which is much cleaner and much less likely to break. Here is one way to do it:

```
    import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub 

class PageOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.query_find_btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "BTN", (40,40))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.AddList, self.query_find_btn)

    def AddList(self, evt):
        pub.sendMessage("listctrlListener", message="Hello")

class PageTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.list1 = wx.ListCtrl(self,-1,wx.Point(0,0),wx.Size(400,400),style=wx.LC_REPORT |   wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.list1.InsertColumn(0,'values')
        pub.subscribe(self.updateListCtrl, "listctrlListener")

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def updateListCtrl(self, message):
        """"""
        self.list1.InsertStringItem(0, message)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title,size=(400,400),pos=wx.Point(100,100), 
        style=wx.SYSTEM_MENU |wx.CAPTION )

        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

        MainFrame = PageOne(nb)
        SecondFrame = PageTwo(nb)

        nb.AddPage(MainFrame, "One")
        nb.AddPage(SecondFrame, "Two")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame=MyFrame(None,-1,'Unknown.py')
        self.frame.Centre()
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

This is using pubsub's newish API. You can see another example of using it here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/05/wxpython-2-9-and-the-newer-pubsub-api-a-simple-tutorial/

If you happen to be using an old version of wxPython (pre-2.8.10), then you'll probably need to use pubsub's older API, which you can read about here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

Also note that I removed the button's id. You shouldn't set the button's id to a low number as it might be used internally by wxPython. It is recommended that if you have to create an id, you should do so like this:

```
btnId = wx.NewId()
```